# Unable to resize img Internet Explorer

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, height, width

I run a website and I've recently published an article which is totally fine on Chrome and FireFox but has some problems with Internet Explorer.

The incriminated page is [this one](http://luigitiburzi.com/i-bought-an-android-phone-what-now/).

I share here for simplicity a portion of the code:

```
<figure class="appFigureElement" id="airDroidFigure">
    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en"><img id="airDroidPicture" class="imageApps" alt="airDroid" src="path to image"/></a>
    <figcaption id="airDroidCaption">
        <p> blablabla </p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>


.imageApps
{
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}


.appFigureElement
{
    padding-bottom: 25px;   
}


function setFigureHeight(figure, picture, caption)
{
    var figureEl = jQuery("#" + figure);
    var pictureEl = jQuery("#" + picture);
    var captionEl = jQuery("#" + caption);

    if(pictureEl.outerHeight(true) > captionEl.outerHeight(true))
        figureEl.height(pictureEl.outerHeight(true));
    else
    {
        figureEl.height(captionEl.outerHeight(true));
        var mrgBott = captionEl.outerHeight(true) - pictureEl.outerHeight(true) + 15;
        pictureEl.css("margin-bottom", mrgBott+"px");
    }



}
```

Basically at the onLoad event I run the js function that formats every 'tile' (figure element) according to the CSS.

The problem is that in IE the CSS is like missing, in the sense that the pictures are extremely huge and no matter how I try resizing them (css inside html, img outside figure and so on) I always get huge images while in Chrome and FF all is nice.

Do you have any suggestion?

Ps the website is developed in WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your style.css, there exists a rule:

```
.ie #content img, .ie #comments img, .ie .sidebar img {
    height: auto;
}
```

That is your culprit.

Just to further explain, this rule is written *AFTER* your rule making it override the .imageApps class that you are sizing the images with. Since it is only applied to IE, that is why you are not seeing this problem in other browsers.

Comment: Should I delete that rule? probably it is written by WordPress and if I delete it I will break something...

Comment: Just make sure that your imageApps rule comes after it in the CSS. Or you can use !important but that is typically frowned upon.